# Product Chatbot v2

Tags: python, list, chatbot

I am trying to create a chatbot that asks for a certain price point and suspension travel range before listing products inside that price point and suspension travel range. However I am unsure how to do this.

```
product = input("product")
price = input(f'do you have a specific price point for {product}s ')
travel = range(160,180)
price = int(price)
prices = {
    "rockymountianslayer" : 1000,
    "norcostorm" : 3000,
    "yetisb165" : 70,
    "instinct_powerplay" : 13000,
    "helkeler" : 2222
}
travels = {
    "rockymountianslayer" : 180,
    "norcostorm" : 100,
    "yetisb165" : 165
}
mountainbikes = ["rockymountianslayer", "norcostorm", "yetisb165", ]
output = []
for i in mountainbikes:
  if prices[i] < price:
    if travels[i] = travel:
    output.append(i)
print(output)
```

I believe this bit is the problem.

```
output = []
for i in mountainbikes:
  if prices[i] < price:
    if travels[i] = travel:
    output.append(i)
print(output)
```

Comment: this is the error message:   `File "program.py", line 27
    if travels[i] = travel:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`    sorry i am not very good at coding.

Comment: Thanks that helps alot.   can i mark your comment as an anwser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python only uses the `=` operator for assignments, not for comparisons. So, to compare a variable to a value you should write `if travels[i] == travel:`, rather than just using `=`. However, in this case, `travel` isn't a value, it's a `range` object, so your comparison should actually be `if travels[i] in travel:` to check if the value in `travels[i]` is within the range.

As an aside, you should try to standardise your indentations on 4 spaces according to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You've used both 4 and 2 spaces in different parts of your code, which might make it harder to immediately spot that `output.append(i)` is incorrectly indented.

Updated to take the above into account, the code should look like:

```
output = []
for i in mountainbikes:
    if prices[i] < price:
        if travels[i] in travel:
            output.append(i)
print(output)
```

As a second aside, you could combine the two `if` statements together:
 `if prices[i] < price and travels[i] in travel:` and, finally, you could simplify your code by using a Python list comprehension to build the new list in a single statement:

```
output = [i for i in mountainbikes if prices[i] < price and travels[i] in travel]
```

Comment: Thank you much, you've really helped me understand it. I will also try and fix the indenting.